# How can I open a pdf with a relative path using the default application in a Qt program

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to open a pdf manual for some hardware from within my application.  It will be triggered from the help menu.  I can't seem to get my application to open a file from a relative path using the OS default application.  I found

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///home/folder/Manual.pdf"));
```

referenced on the Qt forums and this works for me except I am going to install my software on another computer and the absolute path won't be the same.  I'd like to install the manual next to my application and open it with something like

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///Manual.pdf"));
```

but this fails to open with

```
ShellExecute 'file:///Manual.pdf' failed (error 2).
```

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve the absolute path with

```
QString a = QFileInfo("Manual.pdf").absoluteFilePath();
```

then pass it to QUrl, this way:

```
QUrl url = QUrl::fromLocalFile(a);
```

Comment: I think both answers would solve the problem as stated, but this one will probably be better when a different developer comes later makes different assumptions or changes the run directory vs data directory vs executable directory.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If *Manual.pdf* is in the folder of the executable, use:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///" + QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/Manual.pdf"));
```

If you later decide to put the pdf in a dedicated sub-folder, e.g. *doc*, in the code above replace `/Manual.pdf` with `/doc/Manual.pdf`.